# How to get OpenCL running on an NVIDIA JETSON TK1

Tags: opencl, nvidia, tegra

I'm a graduate student from Korea.
Recently, I Started studying OpenCL and the NVIDIA JETSON TK1.

The NVIDIA JETSON K1 can run CUDA programs, so here is my question:
I would like to execute OpenCL kernels on the NVIDIA JETSON, but compiling a simple example, gives me an error message `"CL/cl.h" header no such file or directory`.

So, how should I proceed to compile and execute OpenCL kernel on the NVIDIA JETSON TK1?

Comment: @GeunMoLee there are rumours of OpenCL support coming to the NVIDIA JETSON TK1, including this article: http://www.nvidia.com.mx/content/PDF/tegra_white_papers/Tegra-K1-whitepaper-v1.0.pdf There are also opencl `.so` files for the K1. as for the missing headers you would need to add them manually.